# Cannot convert argument "address", with value: "System.Object[]", for "DownloadString" to type "System.Uri": "Cannot convert the "System.Object[]"

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I need to create a script to make a request on 3 different environment urls, and then generates a CSV file with the average response time of each environment, for each page that I send.

However I get this error:

> Cannot convert argument "address", with value: "System.Object[]", for
>   "DownloadString" to type "System.Uri": "Cannot convert the
>   "System.Object[]"  value of type "System.Object[]" to type
>   "System.Uri".

Here is my code:

```
function ResponseTime($CommonName,$URL, $environment) 
{ 
    $Times = 5 
    $i = 0 
    $TotalResponseTime = 0 

    While ($i -lt $Times) { 
        $Request = New-Object System.Net.WebClient 
        $Request.UseDefaultCredentials = $true 
        $Start = Get-Date 
        $PageRequest = $Request.DownloadString($URL) 
        $TimeTaken = ((Get-Date) - $Start).TotalMilliseconds 
        $Request.Dispose() 
        $i ++ 
        $TotalResponseTime += $TimeTaken 
    } 

    $AverageResponseTime = $TotalResponseTime / $i 
    Write-Host Request to $CommonName took $AverageResponseTime ms in average -ForegroundColor Green 

    $details = @{            
        Date             = get-date              
        AverageResponseTime     = $AverageResponseTime              
        ResponseTime      = $Destination 
        Environment = $environment
    }                           
    $results += New-Object PSObject -Property $details

} 

ResponseTime 'app homepage' 'https://urlproduction', 'PRODUCTION' 
ResponseTime 'app homepage' 'https://urlQA', 'QA' 
ResponseTime 'app homepage' 'https://urltest', 'TEST' 

$results | export-csv -Path c:\so.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Why do you have the comma between the https:// part and the string 'PRODUCTION'... ? *hint*

Comment: Also, cast the url to `[System.Uri]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've encountered a common pitfall in Powershell. Thought the function parameters are separated with commas in the definition, function call parameters are not. Should commas be used, Powershell converts such items as arrays.

In this specific case

```
ResponseTime 'app homepage' 'https://urlproduction', 'PRODUCTION'
```

is parsed as

```
Call function ResponseTime with two parameters:
```

`'app homepage'` and `'https://urlproduction', 'PRODUCTION'` -- in which the later is an array consisting of two elements.

On the other hand

```
ResponseTime 'app homepage' 'https://urlproduction' 'PRODUCTION'
```

is parsed as

```
Call function ResponseTime with three parameters:
```

`'app homepage'`, `'https://urlproduction'` and  `'PRODUCTION'`